# Configurable products mixed with a form. Post info to webservice and charge customers

Tags: configurable-product, magento-community, forms

I'm trying to develop a form in order to pass information to a web service and retrieve a response. To charge customers and manage orders I'm trying to use attribute sets and product type: configurable products combinations to retrieve the correct price and mix that functionality with my form when I send the details. Consequently I will generate the post to the webservice and all the attributes to retrieve the price and generate the order.

My idea is to use a form populated with fields where some of those fields are product attributes defined to retrieve the price of that particular product combination.

My first question is: is it possible to pass that information directly as a button? Example, CMS page -> add to cart button that passes those product variants on click and set the product attribute combination price based on those parameters.

Or: if I extend the product view page how can I parse product attributes to use? Mix those attributes as fields inside my form and use it to bill customer?

Answer (score 1):

'Yes' is the quick answer. In your browser on the product page you should study the JavaScript object `var spConfig` it probably contains everything you need. If it does not contain everything you need then you can override the function:

```
//file: app/core/Mage/Catalog/Product/View.php
//class: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
    public function getJsonConfig(){
       //...
    }
```

Which is called in `view.phtml` to generate `var spConfig`.

Then just use JavaScript to build the appropriate `POST` to the webservice.